# What exactly is Korean chili paste, aka 'gochujang'? Is there any way of making it at home?

Tags: asian-cuisine, korean-cuisine

I have recently started trying out some Korean dishes, some of which use the Korean  chili paste, gochujang. However, I can't seem to find this in any of my local supermarkets.

What exactly is in this paste, which gives it that distinct flavour? Is there any way of making this at home, in a relatively easy way?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Jasmine! Recipe recommendations are outside the scope of this site, but you should be able to find many great gochujang recipes by googling "gochujang recipe" or "how to make gochujang". If you're unhappy with them and need help improving a particular recipe, that we can help with :)

Comment: @mech Greetings! Sorry I seemed to have missed the purpose of this site. Thank you for your kind response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a fermented chili paste made with rice and fermented bean paste.

You could make it at home if you can find all the ingredients. But it looks like a complex recipe and preparation.

For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IqtT0HcXUE

Here's a simpler version (less traditional) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiWJor3DQgI

I would substitute with any other chili paste (sambal oelek...)

Comment: Sambal would be way too spicy for a 1-to-1 substitution, though.  In the US, I'd actually look for a spicy BBQ sauce and combine it with a little miso if I could get it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have tried other chili pastes but it hasn't always got quite the same taste